# Lost master password in Preferences> saved log-ins

Tags: firefox

How do I edit firefox profile to get round having forgotten the master password in Preferences> Saved log-ins?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer here. Than you for your patience.
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/reset-your-master-password-if-you-forgot-it